# Random Node Location without Overlap

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have a problem and I have no idea where to start.

I assign sprite1 to a random location using the following code:

```
let index2 = arc4random() % 3;
        if index2 == 0 {
        sqrite1.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 100  , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    } else if index2 == 1 {
        sprite1.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    } else if index2 == 2{
        sprite1.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 100, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    }
```

I then repeat the above code again, but for sprite2 as follows:

I assign sprite2 to a random location the same way as for sprite 1 using the same code:

```
let index2 = arc4random() % 3;
        if index2 == 0 {
        sqrite2.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 100  , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    } else if index2 == 1 {
        sprite2.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    } else if index2 == 2{
        sprite2.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 100, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    }
```

I then repeat the above code again for the 3rd time, but for sprite3 as follows:

I then assign sprite3 to a random location the same way as for sprite1 and sprite2 using the same code:

```
let index2 = arc4random() % 3;
        if index2 == 0 {
        sqrite3.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 100  , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    } else if index2 == 1 {
        sprite3.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    } else if index2 == 2{
        sprite3.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 100, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    }
```

Now, here are my problem: I want to make sure that sprite1, sprite2 and sprite3 do NOT end up in the same location. How can I do this? I have tried to think about a way to do this, but I have no idea where to start.

Thanks :)

Comment: What about your progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating a function that assigns the node to a random spot.

```
func randomSpot(node: SKSpriteNode) {
    let index2 = arc4random() % 3;
    if index2 == 0 {
         node.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 100  , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    } else if index2 == 1 {
        node.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    } else if index2 == 2{
        node.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 100, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    }
}
```

Then actually randomize it:

```
randomSpot(sprite1)
```

Make sure it isn't in the same spot:

```
randomSpot(sprite2)
while sprite2.position == sprite1.position {
    randomSpot(sprite2)
}
```

And for sprite3:

```
randomSpot(sprit3)
while sprite3.position == sprite1.position || sprite3.position == sprite2.position {
    randomSpot(sprite3)
}
```

Note: you can do it with an extension:

```
extension SKSpriteNode {
    func randomSpot() {
        let index2 = arc4random() % 3;
        if index2 == 0 {
             self.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.parent!.frame) - 100  , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.parent!.frame))
        } else if index2 == 1 {
            self.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.parent!.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.parent!.frame))
        } else if index2 == 2{
            self.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.parent!.frame) + 100, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.parent!.frame))
        }
    }

}
```

And then you would call it:

```
sprite1.randomSpot()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a method to check everytime if your previous numbers were choosed, this is valid for n randomize position, there are no limits:

```
   class GameScene: SKScene {
        var positions = [UInt32]()
        override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
            let index2 = getRandomNum()
            // do whatever you want with index2 for node1
            ...
            let index2 = getRandomNum()
            // do whatever you want with index2 for node2
        }
        func getRandomNum() -> UInt32 {
            var exist : Bool = false
            var index2 : UInt32!
            while !exist {
                index2 = arc4random() % 3
                if !positions.contains(index2) {
                    exist = true
                }
            }
            positions.append(index2)
            return index2
        }
    }
```

Finally about your positions I've thinking about a more elegant method:

```
func setPos(index2:UInt32, sprite:SKSpriteNode) {
        switch index2 {
        case 0:
            sprite.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 100  , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        case 1:
            sprite.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        case 2:
            sprite.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 100, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        default:
            break
        }
}
```

You can do directly all with only 1 line per node:

```
setPos(getRandomNum(),sprite:sprite1)
```